# Justify caption

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions

For my figures and Tables the caption text is formatted to start in the middle. For the tables only however, I need it to start from the left. I tried using `\flushleft` command for it but it did not work. How to make the caption for tables start from the left instead from the middle? I would appreciate all help.

Comment: Which documentclass are you using? Do you already load the `caption` package by any chance?

Comment: I am using `mwart` and I am not loading the `caption` package.

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwcls

Comment: please provide a MWE to get help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you load the `caption` package, just write:

```
\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=off}
```

However this will put the caption at the *page* left margin. If you want to have it on the left side of the *table*, insert your tabular in a `threeparttable`  environment, using the following structure:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
…
\begin{tabular}{…}
……………
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Note what the log says when the `mwart` class is used.

Comment: It says that `caption` is unsupported, but the document still works. How can I overcome this in another way?